# How to send Data Via bundle from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android, double, bundle

How to send double from Activity A via Bundle without going to the  Activity B,

Comment: can you explain your question i am not getting what are you trying to say

Comment: Can you explain your requirement and problem?

Comment: Question not clear, kindly give more explanation and code

Comment: Please explain your question with the help of some code.

Answer (score 3):

**In First Activity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActiity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", etName.getText().toString());
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

**In Second (Reciving) Activity:**

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

  String name = bundle.getString("name");     //use same key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", edtName.getText().toString());
b.putString("surname", edtSurname.getText().toString());
b.putString("email", edtEmail.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("personBdl", b);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Taimoor sir,  i am asking about double rather then string

Comment: And you put the intent in like startActivity(i);

Comment: And i don't want to start the activity B just to send my variable to Activity B ,